# Span all rows of a specific column of a JTable (to render a JTextPane)

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextpane, renderer

I'd like to build a standard JTable but with all rows spanned on one specific column. So that column has to contain only one cell with a JTextPane as its renderer.
Do you know any simply way to do that?

NB: no third part software required.

Thanks.

Comment: @Randy not good enough .. a renderer is applied per-cell, spanning across multiple cells is not supported. There are some oldish examples (basically hacking the ui delegate), but nothing really satisfying (didn't check the commercials)

Comment: How do you interpret that in the underlying model. Will the model have  the same data for each row for that specific column ? Is it not an option to just place a `JTextPane` next to your `JTable`

Comment: @Robin The document in the JTextPane has to be shared by all the rows. I do some modifications depending of values from the JTable. I can separate the `JTextPane` from the `JTable` but I want to put it between 2 left columns et 3 right colums. Do you think I can divide the `JTable` and put the `JTextPane` between the 2 parts?

Comment: You can certainly divide the table. Shouldn't be too hard to write a decorator for a `TableModel` which takes an existing `TableModel` and only exposes some of the columns

Comment: @Robin, you could also use a single `TableModel` and use [`TableRowSorter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableRowSorter.html) to do the filtering.

Comment: @MvG how will a row sorter help in filtering out columns ?

Comment: @Robin: A `TableRowSorter` may provide a view consisting of [fewer rows](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultRowSorter.html#getViewRowCount%28%29) than originally present in the model. I noticed this while reading the `JTable` sources. It is my understanding that one usually makes use of this using some [`RowFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.html). I'm not saying that using this instead of separate models will be the *better* solution, I'm just stating that it might be *one* possible solution.

Comment: @MvG exactly, to filter out *rows*, not *columns*

Comment: @Robin: I read your comment about a decorated model in the light of the original question and thought about multiple tables with spanning labels in between, all of that inside a single scroll view. After that I never noticed you were actually talking about *columns*. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rendering of a `JTable`, including the clipping to the cell rectangle, is buries deep inside the [user interface implementations](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicTableUI.java) of the pluggable look and feel in question. Changing stuff there is going to be messy business, and highly dependent on the actual JFC implementation.

So instead I'd suggest drawing the cells of those roes any way you like, and having another transparent pane on top of the table to overlay those areas with the spanned content you describe. Still messy, probably quite a bit of work, but more likely to be portable.

Comment: +1 for the layered approach - implementation got really simpler with JLayer (new to jdk7)

Answer (score 3):

Triggered by @MvG idea of some kind of *overlay* here's a proof-of-concept using JLayer (added to core in jdk7, for earlier versions, use [JXLayer in SwingLabs](http://jxlayer.java.net) which is very similar)

The basic ingredients:

- a LayerUI which manages a textArea in its glassPane
- a custom layoutManager which sizes/locates the textArea over a column
- some listeners which force a re-layout of the glassPane

It's surprisingly straightforward to at least make it work. There are some rough edges, though:

- as always, navigation in the table: when table has focus, its cell selection is moved under the textArea. Probably needs a custom selectionModel
- during the move of a column, the table rows under the column are visible
- ?? probably another bunch of devils, after all we are confusing the ui :-)

Some code:

```
public static class RowSpanUI extends LayerUI<JTable> {
    public static String COLUMN_TO_SPAN_KEY = "Table.columnToSpan";
    private JLayer layer;
    private JTextArea area;

    @Override
    public void installUI(JComponent c) {
        super.installUI(c);
        this.layer = (JLayer) c;
        installTextArea();
        installListeners();
    }


    @Override
    public void doLayout(JLayer<? extends JTable> l) {
        super.doLayout(l);
        l.getGlassPane().doLayout();
    }

     private void installTextArea() {
        area = new JTextArea(10, 20);
        layer.getGlassPane().setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
        layer.getGlassPane().setLayout(new ColumnLayoutManager(this));
        layer.getGlassPane().add(area);
        layer.getGlassPane().setVisible(true);
    }

    public JTable getView() {
        return (JTable) layer.getView();
    }

    public int getViewColumnToSpan() {
        Object clientProperty = getView().getClientProperty(COLUMN_TO_SPAN_KEY);
        if (clientProperty instanceof Integer) {
            return getView().convertColumnIndexToView((int) clientProperty);
        }   
        return -1;
    }

    /**
     * Install listeners to manually trigger a layout of the glassPane.
     * This is incomplete, just the minimum for demonstration!
     */
    protected void installListeners() {
        ComponentListener compL = new ComponentListener() {

            @Override
            public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
                doLayout(layer);
            }

            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                doLayout(layer);
            }

            @Override
            public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
                doLayout(layer);
            }

            @Override
            public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };
        layer.addComponentListener(compL);

        TableColumnModelListener columnL = new TableColumnModelListener() {

            @Override
            public void columnRemoved(TableColumnModelEvent e) {
                doLayout(layer);
            }

            @Override
            public void columnMoved(TableColumnModelEvent e) {
                doLayout(layer);
            }

            @Override
            public void columnMarginChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                doLayout(layer);
            }

            @Override
            public void columnAdded(TableColumnModelEvent e) {
                doLayout(layer);
            }

            @Override
            public void columnSelectionChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            }

        };
        getView().getColumnModel().addColumnModelListener(columnL);
    }

}

public static class ColumnLayoutManager implements LayoutManager {

    private RowSpanUI ui;

    public ColumnLayoutManager(RowSpanUI ui) {
        this.ui = ui;
    }

    @Override
    public void layoutContainer(Container parent) {
        Component child = parent.getComponent(0);
        child.setBounds(getColumnBounds());
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container parent) {
        return ui.getView().getSize();
    }

    protected Rectangle getColumnBounds() {
        int viewColumn = ui.getViewColumnToSpan();
        if (viewColumn < 0) {
            return new Rectangle();
        }
        Rectangle r = ui.getView().getCellRect(0, viewColumn, false);
        r.height = ui.getView().getHeight();
        return r;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container parent) {
        return preferredLayoutSize(parent);
    }
    @Override
    public void addLayoutComponent(String name, Component comp) {
    }

    @Override
    public void removeLayoutComponent(Component comp) {
    }
}

// usage
JTable table = new JTable(myModel);
table.putClientProperty(RowSpanUI.COLUMN_TO_SPAN_KEY, 2);
JLayer layer = new JLayer(table, new RowSpanUI());
```

Comment: I omit to precise that: I work with JDK6. And I can't use any third-part lib. But seems to be relatively nice solution.